# Database not seeding with proper factories and seeder class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-8

The Problem is my database not seeded with `php artisan db:seed` in my laravel project. no errors showing and after the command my database just empty but `php artisan db:seed` showing success result.

This is my run method in DatabaseSeeder.php file under database/seeders folder in my laravel project.

```
$this->call([
    ItemBrandSeeder::class,
    ItemDepartmentSeeder::class,
    ItemUnitSeeder::class,
    CategorySeeder::class,
    ItemSeeder::class
]);
```

This is my run method in ItemBrandSeeder.php under database/seeders folder in my laravel project.

```
ItemBrandFactory::times(100);
```

This is my definition method in ItemBrandFactory.php under database/factories folder in my laravel project.

```
return [
    'stvalue1' => $this->faker->randomElement(['BOX', 'PCS', 'NOS', 'PACK']),       
    'stdescription' => $this->faker->text('30'),
    'stvalue2' => $this->faker->randomElement(['Countable', 'Measurable']),
    'stflag' => "UNIT"
];
```

This is my run method in ItemDepartmentSeeder.php under database/seeders folder in my laravel project.

```
ItemDepartmentFactory::times(25);
```

This is my definition method in ItemDepartmentFactory.php under database/factories folder in my laravel project.

```
return [
    'stCategory' => $this->faker->text(25),
    'sttype' => ['department']
];
```

This is my run method in ItemUnitSeeder.php under database/seeders folder in my laravel project.

```
DB::connection("dynamic_db")->table('tblgeneral')->insert([
    [
        'stflag' => 'UNIT',
        'stdescription' => "Pieces",
        'stvalue1' => "PCS",
        'stvalue2' => "Countable"
    ],

    [
        'stflag' => 'UNIT',
        'stdescription' => "Box",
        'stvalue1' => "BOX",
        'stvalue2' => "Countable"
    ],

    [
        'stflag' => 'UNIT',
        'stdescription' => "Bar",
        'stvalue1' => "BAR",
        'stvalue2' => "Measurable"
    ],

    [
        'stflag' => 'UNIT',
        'stdescription' => "Nos",
        'stvalue1' => "NOS",
        'stvalue2' => "Measurable"
    ],

    [
        'stflag' => 'UNIT',
        'stdescription' => "Feet",
        'stvalue1' => "FT",
        'stvalue2' => "Measurable"
    ],
]);
```

There is no factory class for ItemUnitSeeder
This is my run method in CategorySeeder.php under database/seeders folder in my laravel project.

```
CategoryFactory::times(50);
```

This is my definition method in CategoryFactory.php under database/factories folder in my laravel project.

```
return [
    'stCategory' => $this->faker->text(25),
    'sttype' => ['category']
];
```

This is my run method in ItemSeeder.php under database/seeders folder in my laravel project.

```
ItemFactory::times(1000);
```

This is my definition method in ItemFactory.php under database/factories folder in my laravel project.

```
$edate = array(\Carbon\Carbon::create('1973-09-17 04:30:43'), \Carbon\Carbon::now())[rand(0, 1)];
$unit2 = array('na', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)[rand(0, 5)];
$purchasePrice = $this->faker->numberBetween(200, 10000);
$retailPrice = $purchasePrice + ($this->faker->numberBetween(5, 40) / 100 * $purchasePrice);
$minPrice = $retailPrice + $this->faker->numberBetween(0, 50);
$supplierGivenDiscount = $this->faker->numberBetween(0, 10);
$retailDiscount = $this->faker->numberBetween(0, 5);
$unit2Def = $this->faker->numberBetween(2, 12);
$unit2Price = ($retailPrice / $unit2Def) / 100 * rand(1, 50);
$wholesalePrice = $retailPrice - $this->faker->numberBetween(0, 5) / 100 * $retailPrice;
$wholesaleDiscount = $wholesalePrice - $this->faker->numberBetween(0, 3) / 100 * $wholesalePrice;

return [
    'stItemCode' => getSerialNo('item'),
    'stDescription' => $this->faker->text(100),
    'stCategory' => rand(0, 50),
    'stUnit1' => rand(0, 5),
    'stBrand' => rand(0, 100),
    'stDepartment' => rand(0, 25),
    'stDescription2' => $this->faker->text(200),
    'daEdate' => $edate,
    'tiContaminable' => $edate->eq(\Carbon\Carbon::create('1973-09-17 04:30:43')),
    'dbMinPrice' => $minPrice,
    'dbPurchasePrice' => $purchasePrice,
    'dbSupplierGivenDiscount' => $supplierGivenDiscount,
    'dbRetailPrice' => $retailPrice,
    'dbRetailPriceDiscount' => $retailDiscount,
    'stShelf' => rand(0, 30),
    'siItemType' => rand(0, 3),
    'stUnit2' => $unit2,
    'dbUnit2Price' => $unit2 != 'na' ? $unit2Price : 0,
    'dbUnit2Def' => $unit2 != 'na' ? $unit2Def : 0,
    'dbWholeSalesPrice' => $wholesalePrice,
    'dbWholeSalesPriceDiscount' => $wholesaleDiscount,
    'dbReorderLevel' => 0,
    'stBranch' => Branch::all()->toArray()[rand(0, Branch::count())]['id'],
    'stWebUpdateStatus' => 1,
];
```

Command and output in console

[image: Command and output in console]

But in my database **no data are seeded** my database just empty.

In case if your wonder why am I used DB class to create ItemUnits in ItemUnitSeeder.php file  its because I only wanted 5 units so I thought making a Factory for that useless.

Category factory, Item brand factory and Item department factory using same table name called "tblCategory" only different is "sttype" field. if "sttype" is set to "category" than it's category and if it is set to "brand" than its brand and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and there is no problem, but I think your problem is here:
Instead of using `times()`
Use a factor like this:
`Item::factory()->count(1000)->create();`

Comment: `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory::count() cannot be called statically`

Comment: you must call factory trough  Model:
`YourModelName::factory()->count(1000)->create();`